Unable to give permission to app to access devices on local network on Sequoia - no prompt given
I am developing an app using NWJS framework, which accesses devices on the local network.  I am doing this on Sequoia on Macos (Desktop).
My issue is, I am unable to give my app permission to app to access devices on local network.
Other apps which I have used which access devices on the local network, on first-time launching, have given a prompt asking me if I want to allow or deny access to local device for the app.
However, on first-time launching (and many others after that), It simply says the device cannot be reached, and I never get a prompt asking me if I want to allow or deny access to local device for my app.
In its barebones proof-of-concept stage of my app, I have an iframe who's src attribute is the IP address of a device known on the network with that address.  I have tried the protocol https://192.168.1.99 and http://192.168.1.99 in the src attribute.  This protocol works in another app I have built where upon first-time launch, I was able to get a prompt and give it the needed permission.
If I check in System Settings > Privacy and Security > Network, the app doesn't appear where I can toggle a setting.  I also am unable to explicitly add my app to the list.
How can I tell my Mac to allow my app to have permission for local network access?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Your app must have this entitlement to send or receive IP multicast or broadcast on iOS. It also allows your app to browse and advertise arbitrary Bonjour service types.
This entitlement requires permission from Apple before you can use it in your app. Request permission from the Multicast Networking Entitlement Request page."
com.apple.developer.networking.multicast (developer.apple.com)

Thank you for the quick reply.  I think that may be the answer.  After adding this key, I got the prompt and was able to give it permission.  I am still unable to connect "192.168.1.99 refused to connect" (for http) and "The webpage at https://192.168.1.182/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."  But that may be another problem.

Interesting, this worked the first time, but when I tried the same thing on another app, it didn't work :-/

Questions about software development are off topic here, strictly speaking. Yours would be better addressed to the Apple developer forum.
